# How to do a geoip lookup in php?

Tags: php, geoip

All tutorials I have seen have pointed towards functions like `geoip_record_by_name`. I always get this error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function geoip_record_by_name() in /home/<acct>/public_html/geoip.php on line <line>`

I'm on "shared" hosting, meaning I don't have access to install the PECL geoip extension.

What are other (free!) ways to perform geoip lookups? Preferably ones which don't depend on an external service?

Comment: There's a few services that let you download a coarse-granularity database in csv format that'll make IPS down to country level. But otherwise you're stuck with an external service. You could probably recreate that geoip_*() function with some CURL calls, if the provider's API isn't too horrible.

Comment: How do those services determine where your IP address is? How do THEY get the locations to begin with? How could I instead generate my own database?

Comment: Why make your own database when there are free APIs that will give you theirs?  It would take a single person years to create their own database from scratch.

Comment: @imoda How are they even generated?

Comment: @Cyclone I wouldn't know the specifics.  I assume it's a pretty meticulous process.

Comment: @imoda: And that process would entail...? Ping speedtests? Manual user data entry? Random guessing? Querying a government database? Dartboard? Flipping the bits using butterflies? I suppose it'd be possible to triangulate a user's location if you have enough servers to ping speedtest.

Comment: @Cyclone "I wouldn't know the specifics."

Comment: @Cyclone: they do the legwork and mine the IANA databases for IP block assignments, and follow things down the assignment chain and contact each block holder to ask "hey, where's your IPs?"

Comment: @imoda: So your assumption has no basis on evidence? Sorry, I'm just really confused about how you could think it would take forever and be a meticulous process when you have no idea about the inner workings. It sounds like you're as in the dark as I am, lol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have MySQL server, there are IP databases that you can use and install for free, then do a `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` and run it against the database data.

i.e. (based on some arbitrary db)

```
<?php

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT *
                          FROM ips
                          WHERE ip = {$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}
                          LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    $city = $row['city'];
    $state = $row['state'];
    $country = $row['country'];

?>
```

Some databases(Or just [google](http://tinyurl.com/66c7dz3) it): http://www.ipinfodb.com/ip_database.php

**EDIT**

You can also do JSON/XML requests from other APIs and parse the data:

i.e. (Using ipinfodb.com again)

```
$doc->loadXML(file_get_contents("http://api.ipinfodb.com/v2/ip_query.php?key=your_key&ip=" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "&timezone=false")); 

$country = $doc->getElementsByTagName('CountryName')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Comment: Is there any way to generate your own database?

Comment: Left a comment on your original question.  Sure, you COULD make your own database, but there's not really a quick and easy way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try hostip.info, Maxmind or ip2location to name a few. These are easy to use with PHP and can be used on shared hosting. Some of them have offline options as well.

Comment: The first and last were off by a good 50 miles, Maxmind was a bit closer but not much...

Comment: @Cyclone: You get what you pay for.