# Get U.S. state from IP address

Tags: php, ip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is there a good PHP geolocation service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724971/is-there-a-good-php-geolocation-service)

Is it possible to determine which state a visitor to a web page is from based on their IP address? I know you can get this data (and relative location data) from searching their IP addresses using the various WHOIS tools out there, but I'm not sure how I would achieve this on a single web page. I want to display some contextual information to visors on my site.

Comment: see also [How to do a geoip lookup in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499145/how-to-do-a-geoip-lookup-in-php/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install the [`GeoIP`](http://pecl.php.net/package/geoip) extension.

Comment: Thanks, this looks just like what I need!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Maxmind's PHP API](http://www.maxmind.com/app/php) for Geo IP lookup with their [GeoLiteCity free](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity) database.