# Need to set session if country is australia

Tags: php, ip

how can I check if the country is Australia? I need to set a session if country is Australia.

```
207.209.7.0   | 207.209.7.255
```

This is the range IP of australia.

How can I use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` in that part without database, just a simple if statement

Comment: lol ... i never knew AU only have 256 ip available

Comment: *Why*? What could you want this for?

Comment: I have an online store, but i need to set a session if australia only. because i need to change the currency. Only Australia.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you shoud know that this isn't guaranteed.  People can get around it, data will never be 100% complete, etc.

Simply checking a block of IPs is not acceptable.  You need to use a geolcation database, such as [MaxMind's GeoIP](http://www.maxmind.com/app/ip-location).  The free database is good enough for country-level geolocation.

Comment: is there a very simple way to detect if 1 country only.. thanks for your answer..

Comment: How is this database not simple?  Do you have a question about it?  There is example code on their site.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499145/how-to-do-a-geoip-lookup-in-php/6499182#6499182) about how to detect someone's location in php. Then add your condition.

Since you don't want to use a database I would recommend

```
$doc->loadXML(file_get_contents("http://api.ipinfodb.com/v2/ip_query.php?key=your_key&ip=" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "&timezone=false")); 

$country = $doc->getElementsByTagName('CountryName')->item(0)->nodeValue;

if ($country == 'australia') {

    // set session
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely know the ranges of valid IP Addresses, you could do something like:

```
function ip2number($IP) {
    $parts = explode('.', $IP);
    if(count($parts) != 4) return 0;
    return ($parts[3] + $parts[2] * 256 + $parts[1] * 256 * 256 + $parts[0] * 256 * 256 * 256);
}

$num = ip2number($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
if($num >= ip2number('207.209.7.0') && $num <= ip2number('207.209.7.255')) {
    echo "Valid";
}
```

Like Brad says though, it isn't guaranteed and there are ways around it, and you will have to keep up to date of the valid IP Address ranges.